# validate checkboxes using php

Tags: php

I have a form with series of checkboxes with the same name of 'name=category[]'. And now I need to count how many checkboxes are selected by a user. Further I need to check at least 1 checkbox is being selected or upto 10 checkboxes.

This is the way that I am trying so far...

```
if ( isset ( $_POST['category']) {

  if (( sizeof( $_POST['category']) == 10 || sizeof( $_POST['category']) <= 10 )) {

     // form processing....

  } else {

      echo 'Atleast 1, not more than 10 categories.';
  }

} else {

  echo 'Please select atleast one category.';

}
```

can anybody tell me is there an another way to accomplish this task? That mean, to get this two errors...

Comment: `<= 10` test contains already `== 10`, so you can use just `<= 10`.

Comment: count ($_POST['category']) ?

Comment: sizeof( $_POST['category']) <= 10

Comment: above code not going to inner else part..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question you want to check only the selected checkbox count.

As per my knowledge the values for checkbox are either 'on' or 'off'. If you will make a count of the name 'category' it'll give you all checkbox count displayed on the page irrespective of clicked or not-clicked.

so filter it out and count

put this function before if condition starting.
Formated code...

```
    function nonzero($var) {
        return $var !="off" ? "on" :'';
    }
    if ( isset ( $_POST['category']) { 
        $_POST['category'] = array_filter($_POST['category'], 'nonzero');
        if ( sizeof( $_POST['category'] ) >= 1 //check of at-least one is checked
             && sizeof( $_POST['category'] ) <= 10 ) { //check for at-most 10 is checked
            form processing();
        } else { 
            echo 'At-least 1, not more than 10 categories.'; 
        } 
    } else { 
        echo 'Please select at-least one category.'; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but I am confusing with it... please can you update answer with my code?

Answer (score 1):

When handling input arrays, it's good to check it is an array as well as isset:

```
if (isset($_POST['category']) && is_array($_POST['category'])) {

  $totalChecked = count($_POST['category']);

  if ($totalChecked >= 1 && $totalChecked <= 10) {

     // form processing....

  } else {
      echo 'Atleast 1, not more than 10 categories.';
  }

} else {
  echo 'Please select atleast one category.';
}
```